# How can I get I fix this jQuery loop to give me what I want?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

Note: This is CoffeeScript.

I've tried every iteration of this I can think of.

I want to loop through child elements and get the ids of the `select` child of each:

```
$(this).closest(".control-group").nextUntil("#attribute_list").each (key, ele)->
  console.log $(ele).children("select").attr("id")
```

I keep seeing "undefined" in the console log.

That element HAS a single child that is a `select`. I just can't get it. No matter what I do.

Comment: does the select have a class or id we can target?

Comment: What does the HTML look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$( @ ).closest ".control-group"
    .nextUntil "#attribute_list" 
    .each ( key, ele ) ->
        console.log( $( ele ).find( "select" ).attr( "id" ) )
```

note: this assumes the latest coffeescript compiler `1.7`

Use this to upgrade:

```
sudo npm install -g coffee-script
```

Comment: That's exactly the same as the code they're using, you've just changed the formatting a little bit.

Comment: @muistooshort correct formatting makes or breaks coffeescript. I also added `find()` instead of the op's `children()` and () around the logging statement. it might help solve his issue

Comment: But the formatting is equivalent. `find` instead of `children` might make a difference though, can't say without knowing what the HTML looks like.

Comment: I was able to use "this" and I didn't need to pass (key, ele), but "find" was critical. "children" kept giving me "undefined".

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be using `$(this)` in this instance:

```
$(this).closest(".control-group").nextUntil("#attribute_list").each->
  console.log $(this).children("select").attr("id")
```

Comment: But the element is also passed to the `each` callback in the second argument: http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: I was able to use "this", but I needed to use "find" instead of "children".